# How to create sub AlertDialog/Dialog box in Android?

Tags: android, dialog

I need to develop a menu in Android, so for that I am using AlertDialog. But the problem that I am getting is that , how do I develop menu with sub AlertDialog/Dialog. I hope the picture will make everything clear. And in the same time the Dialog should have back button so that if a user desires he would be able to move to the first menu. Thanks

[image: mock-up of sub menus with AlertDialog/Dialog]

Answer (score 0):

How about this - when you create `AlertDialog` 2, pass in the context of `AlertDialog` 1, using `dialog.getContext()` (instead of, say, passing in the original `Activity`).. and so on? I believe that would make `AlertDialog` 2 "appear over" `AlertDialog` 1. Cancelling dialog 2 or pressing back button should take you back to dialog 1.

You could extend the same notion to dialog 3 (i.e, pass in the context of dialog 2 while creating dialog 3) .. and so on.

Answer (score 0):

why dialogs?

i think, it is possible to call multiple dialogs.

but i would suggest (though unconventional) you can have **PreferenceActivity** which can nest menus. remember setting pages.

and for blocking the main UI (if you want) you can invoke the activity with a **dialog theme**.

this will be easier to code and maintain. and you can have your back button as well.

you can call **activity for result** and get the result in the main activity.